# better way to convert the uppercase to lowercase

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am developing an xsl in which I am getting an id and I am converting it in lower case as shown below

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:if test="translate( ./Id ,
                         'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                         'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
              = 'good'
```

please let me know is there any other better way also to achieve the same amy function which xslt 1.0 supports.

Comment: That's the standard way to do it, yes.  Are you looking for a better way just to see if there is one, or is there a particular shortcoming in your current approach?

Answer (score 1):

Not in pure XSLT 1.0, no, its string manipulation facilities are rather limited.  Depending on the processor you might be able to call an extension function (e.g. Xalan lets you call into Java static methods from XPath) but you're probably better off sticking to the native `translate` approach.  If you're doing lots of these conversions you can make it more succinct by declaring a couple of global variables

```
<xsl:variable name="uc" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
<xsl:variable name="lc" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
```

which would let you say `translate(Id, $uc, $lc)` instead of spelling the alphabet out in full every time.